# ASP.NET Web api, multiple applications under same host name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

Lets say that I have multiple internal ASP.NET web api applications. i.e.

- http://service1.something.com/bob/bill
- http://service2.something.com/pete
- http://service3.something.com/dancing/dragon

I would like to expose these different services under a common host name

- http://something.com/service1/bob/bill
- http://something.com/service2/pete
- http://something.com/service3/dancing/dragon

The reason I'm thinking of this setup is to allow each service to run a different set of middleware, but give the client a uniform URL structure to use. Each service can then be upgraded indepently of the others.

Ideally this should be using the latest version of ASP.NET and potentially hosted on Service Fabric. It doesn't have to run on the new core stack, the full .NET framework is acceptable.

I've read that the WebListener supports port sharing, so that is something I'm considering.

Suggestions?

Comment: That's a *networking* question, at best related to IIS configuration - just add another virtual directory or web application under the root site. On Azure youi'll have to search how to route specific URLs to specific services

Comment: Trying to stay out of IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with ASP.NET applications in Service Fabric:

```
service 1: http://something.com/service1/bob/bill
service 2: http://something.com/service2/pete
service 3: http://something.com/service3/dancing/dragon
```

As long as you use a web stack that supports port sharing. On windows, that means using a web stack that uses the http.sys kernel driver. Here are the web hosting options currently available for ASP.NET on Service Fabric:

- The WebListener host in ASP.NET Core 1 is based on HttpListener which uses http.sys, so that will work.
- Kestrel in ASP.NET Core 1 is not based on http.sys and to my knowledge does not support port sharing, so that won't work.
- Katana uses HttpListener so that will also work.

Comment: The WebListener is the one I'm thinking of trying out. Knew the information abotu Kestrel, but not about Katana. Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Azure Fabric every service should have different port - port sharing is available for service replicas (statefull) or multiple instances of the same service (stateless).
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources/

Common way to have uniform URL structure is to create Api Gateway, which will call other services.
http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Comment: For more formal test systems and production, I'm thinking of using the Azure API management. But I'd like to have single point on a dev machine as well. With 40+ devs, it would be nice too keep it out of Azure API